# how to format date dd-MMM-yyy in laravel?

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

Hi I would like to ask you a question I would like to format date "01-Sep-2017" in laravel the below is my code.

```
$toDate = Carbon::now()->format('dd-MMM-yyyy');
```

Comment: try 'F',  http://php.net/manual/pl/function.date.php

Comment: Try: `Carbon::now()->format('DD-MM-YYYY');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
$toDate = date('d-M-y', strtotime("01-Sep-2017"));
```

[From the stackoverflow answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40038521/change-the-date-format-in-laravel-view-page)

Comment: Thank you so much.