# Laravel 5.5 formatting the result in pluck method

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have the following code to get the date value in the (Y-m-d H:i:s) format. I need to get the value in (Y-m-d) format while retrieving. Is it possible to use a function in pluck method?

```
$dates = $this->collection->pluck('date');
```

Comment: Is the `date` attribute a `DateTime` instance, or a string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [change the date format in laravel view page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40038521/change-the-date-format-in-laravel-view-page)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `map()` instead of `pluck()`, which will then allow you to modify the value returned as required:

```
// If $model->date is a DateTime object
$dates = $this->collection->map(function ($model) {
    return $model->date->format('Y-m-d');
});

// If $model->date is a string
$dates = $this->collection->map(function ($model) {
    return date('Y-m-d', strtotime($model->date));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check [Date Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators) and [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon) which is the approach choose by Laravel to format dates.
You will need to have something like this in your model :

`protected $dateFormat = 'd-m-Y';`

And then, in the view when you simply loop over your collection and call `{{ $dates }}` it will display your date formatted in 'd-m-Y'.

Comment: Calling `pluck` on a `Collection` will return a `Collection`. `strtotime` expects a string value, not a `Collection`.