# Trying to render the date

Tags: php, html, laravel-5

I have this code,

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="date-created">Date Created</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    @if (isset($post->created_at))
      <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date-created" name="created_at" value="{{ date('d/m/Y', strtotime($post->created_at)) }}">
    @else
      <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date-created" name="created_at" placeholder="Enter the date the blog post created">
    @endif
  </div>
</div>
```

What I am trying to do is, display the date back from the database to the input box of type allowing user to edit the date.

but this was shown when rendering on the browser

[image]

What the best thing to do with that?

This may be a simple problem, but I don't find a simple explanation for why it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Try change the format from: `date('d/m/Y',...`  to `date('d-m-Y',`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40038521/change-the-date-format-in-laravel-view-page?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: still not working ....

Comment: Have you tried this with a default `<input type="text">` first to confirm if it's just an issue with the formatting with a `type="date"` field or if there's actually something wrong with your template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you are doing wrong is the date format, which is `YYYY-MM-DD` according to the [Mozilla Developers Guide for the `<input type="date">` field](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#Value). So you only need to switch your date format string to `Y-m-d`.

Alternatively, you can also use the `Carbon` approach mentioned by AntonyMN and use the function `toDateString()`. If you set `created_at` field as part of the `$date` fields with `protected $dates = ['created_at'];` in your model, you won't even need to parse the date string into a Carbon object. The model will simply return a Carbon object on demand.

By the way, I don't think using a placeholder works on a date input field due to the fixed format of the input.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel comes with [Carbon nesbot](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) included out of the box to help format date. Dates in laravel can be easily formatted like this:

```
{{\Carbon\Carbon::parse($post->created_at)->format('d/m/Y') }}

{{\Carbon\Carbon::parse($post->created_at)->format('jS M Y') }}
```

Just showing some options. You can get the full documentation on date formats [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

In your case, the code should be

```
@if (isset($post->created_at))
  <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date-created" name="created_at" value="{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($post->created_at)->format('d/m/Y') }}">
@else
  <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date-created" name="created_at" placeholder="Enter the date the blog post created">
@endif
```

Comment: Sorry ... I forgot something ... I am making an edit now. I have added `::parse` to tell carbon to parse the date

Comment: hm i dont realy know why it doesnt work, i tried combination of value, outside laravel, but got the same

Comment: Edited to suit your situation

Comment: @AntonyMN Just a heads up, `created_at` and `updated_at`, if connected to a Model in Laravel are, by default, `Carbon` variables, so you wouldn't need to call instantiate them again (via `::parse()`). You should just be able to call `$post->created_at->format()`