# How to display I like it laravel format created_at timestamp

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

```
echo `{{$result->created_at}}`
```

result is `2018-06-23 08:05:14`
but I want to echo just date. not time
I mean echo only 2018-06-23 not 2018-06-23 08:05:14

Comment: Possible duplicate of [change the date format in laravel view page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40038521/change-the-date-format-in-laravel-view-page)

Comment: Laravel has Carbon date handling built in. https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Answer (score 4):

It's a Carbon instance. The recommended option is simply

```
{{ $result->created_at->toDateString() }}
```

Carbon docs: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-formatting

Comment: Thank you @RossWilson. :) Really should have caught that myself.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty simple, directly escape date to whichever format you want like in the example below

```
 {{ date('Y-m-d', strtotime($result->created_at))}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may handle this on the PHP side by just using `substr`:

```
echo {{ substr($result->created_at, 0, 10) }}
```

There are also ways that you could handle the formatting on the MySQL side, e.g. by using `DATE_FORMAT`:

```
DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use laravel Accessor by put the following method inside your model:

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($date)
{
    return $date->format('Y-m-d');
}
```