# Can't remove hours and minutes from datatable

Tags: laravel, datatables, metronic

I'm trying to get release date field with `y-m-d` format.. Actually time format (for y-m-d) seems fine but also it gives h:m:s too, I changed time format at server side and removed h:m:s but datatable still shows them

What I get

```
2012-04-11 00:00:00
```

What I want

```
2012-04-11
```

Released_at field (Metronic theme - json datatable)

```
{
  field: "released_at",
  title: "Release Date",
  type: "date",
  format: "YYYY/MM/DD"
}
```

time format (I'm using laravel framework)

```
protected $dateFormat = "Y-m-d";
```

How do I fix this ?

Comment: Can you show your migration for this table?

Comment: @RossWilson `$table->dateTime("released_at")->nullable();`

Comment: Hi @Hasan Tıngır, did you tried to use `date('d-m-Y', strtotime($user->from_date));` as said over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40038541/5813861)

Comment: Hi @Hasan Tıngır, If your table contain datatype datetime for `released_at` , then datatable always append time next to it.

Comment: @yash seems  you're right, I changed column as "date" format and now hours gone.. you may add comment as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Datatable accept column type same as mysql type.**

You are trying to convert mysql `dateTime` column to `Date` in datatable, which is not possible from datatable.

In your code you have declared

```
format: "YYYY/MM/DD" // but actual type is dateTime as per mysql.So it will append time next to it.
```

If you are storing only date in mysql then you can change column type to `Date`, and your problem gets solved.

And if you want to convert string to date in laravel you can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40038521/change-the-date-format-in-laravel-view-page) post.

Answer (score 1):

Your database column is of type `dateTime` which, by definition, includes both date and time information. If you want to remove the time at a database level then use the `date` type instead

```
$table->date("released_at")->nullable();
```

If instead of removing the time from the database, you just want to ignore it for certain parts of your application, you can leverage the fact than in Laravel all dates coming from your models are `Carbon\Carbon` instances, so you could do

```
$model->releasedAt->format('y-m-d'); // Returns '18-09-11'
```

Comment: but I already changed time format with `protected $dateFormat = "Y-m-d";` it shows time as `y-m-d` format . There is a problem with datatable