# Laravel query with eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, twig

Good morning.

I have a question that I can't solve with eloquent, let me put it in context.

I have several farms I need all the subscribers of that farm that are taken out through a pivot table and in turn all the receipts of those subscribers, so far so good.
The problem comes in that I put a condition in the dates of the receipts, and I want that it does not extract the subscribers that do not fulfill that condition.

```
 $estates = Estate::with(['adminEstate.neighbours' => function ($query) use ($past_date_init) {
            $query->with(['receiptHeader' => function ($query2) use ($past_date_init) {
                $query2
                    ->where('receipt_h_billing_init', '<=', $past_date_init)
                    ->where('receipt_h_billing_end', '>=', $past_date_init);
                $query2->with('receiptDetail');
            }
            ]);
        }])->get();
```

If they do not meet the date condition, I will not be able to get the subscribers.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please attach the format of the date in the query condition. also make sure that your `date` fields was set in the models in `$dates` var so laravel will referer your field as a date.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49389521/3460080

Comment: I think you want to filter your base model based on the condition applied to your relationship, means you want to remove `adminEstate.neighbours` which doesn't meet the condition in 'receiptHeader' (in other words doesn't return a dataset after the condition)  right ?

Answer (score 0):

Well for now you can use

```
query2
 ->whereDate('receipt_h_billing_init', '<=', $past_date_init)
 ->whereDate('receipt_h_billing_end', '>=', $past_date_init);

query2
     ->whereBetween(DB::raw('Date(receipt_h_billing_init)'),[$past_date_init,  $past_date_init]);
```

as you can see here I didn't use `whereBetween` because it will compare also the time the first one will work fine